# Formal definition of union of arbitrary sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Usually one sees something like this:

### Finite case

Let $n \in \mathbf{N}$ and $A_1,...,A_n$ be sets. Then $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ exists and is defined to be the object (set) satisfying $$\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i=\{x \ | \ \exists j \in \{1,...,n\}: x \in A_j \}.$$

This has the usual "..." notation which I would like to formalize.

### Arbitrary case

Let $I$ be a set and $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of sets. Then $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ exists and ist defined to be the set satisfying $$\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i=\{x \ | \ \exists j \in I : x \in A_j\}$$

**Question:** Is the following way to try and formalize this correct?

Let $I,S$ be sets, where $S$ contains only sets as elements and $f:I \to S$ be a function. Then by definition of a function, for all $i \in I$ there exists an object $A \in S$ such that $f(i)=A$.  We define $A_i:=f(i)$ for all $i \in I$. Intuitively we have then defined a set $A_i$ for all $i$. and as far as I know, this is the definition of an indexed family $(A_i)_{i \in I}$.

Now, the set $\{A_i : i \in I\}$ exists (why? is this by the axiom of restriced comprehension?) and is a subset of $S$. By the axiom of union, there then exists a set, whose elements are exactly the $A_i$'s. More precisely, there exists a set $M$ with $$\forall x : x \in M \iff \exists i \in I: x \in A_i.$$ The set $M$ is then denoted by $$M=\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i.$$

**Another question:** We use the notation $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ here, why can we do this? Can we always introduce an arbitrary notation for new objects?

Comment: Suppose $I = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}.$ Then $$\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i = A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4$$  It is a generalization, like $\sum_{i=1}^4 i =  1+2+3+4$.

Comment: @amWhy It's not really shorthand though, it's a proper generalization - it applies even if $I$ doesn't come with a natural ordering (or any ordering at all, if we drop choice).

Comment: "*Can we always introduce an arbitrary notation for new objects?*" why not, its just a notation.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot to unpack here.

First, your statement that $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i$ is defined to be the set $\{x \mid \exists j \in I (x \in A_j)\}$ is correct. But it doesn't tell the whole story.

The whole story goes as follows:

First, we define something called the "basic union". Given a family $\mathcal{F}$ of sets, $\bigcup \mathcal{F}$ is defined to be the set $\{x \mid \exists F \in \mathcal{F} (x \in F)\}$. In other words, $\bigcup \mathcal{F}$ is the unique set $Z$ such that $\forall x (x \in Z \iff \exists F \in \mathcal{F} (x \in F))$.

How do we know that $\bigcup \mathcal{F}$ exists? That is, how do we know there is such a $Z$ such that $\forall x (x \in Z \iff \exists F \in \mathcal{F} (x \in F))$? The existence of such a $Z$ is guaranteed by the axiom of union.

How do we know that such a $Z$ is a unique? We can prove it is unique using the axiom of extensionality.

The use of this $\bigcup$ notation is what is known as a "definitional extension". In general, if we are working in a system of first-order logic and can prove $\forall x_1 \ldots \forall x_n \exists ! y (P(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y))$, where $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y)$ is some formal expression whose free variables consist only of $x_1, \ldots, x_n, y$, then we can introduce a new $n$-ary function symbol $f$ together with the axiom $\forall x_1 \ldots \forall x_n (P(x_1, \ldots, x_n, f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)))$. In other words, we define $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ to be the unique $y$ such that $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y)$.

In set theory, we use definition extensions to define all sorts of things. Constants are just $0$-ary functions, so when we use notation like $\emptyset$ and $\omega$, we are using definitional extensions. We also use definitional extensions to define notation like $\{x\}$, $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$, $A \times B$, $\{x \in A \mid P(x)\}$, $A \cap B$, and more.

However, sometimes this sort of definitional extension is not enough. The problem is that we sometimes need to introduce notation that is only valid some of the time. The simplest example here is division - if we're working in the theory of arithmetic, we want to use the expression $\frac{a}{b}$ even though it's *a priori* possible that $b$ is zero.

Typically, when we introduce notation in mathematics, we use a "partial definitional extension". In this case, we have some predicate $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y)$ and we can prove that there is at most one $y$ such that $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y)$ (though we can't necessarily prove such a $y$ exists). We then introduce the notation $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ to refer to the unique $y$ such that $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y)$. The caveat is that whenever we use the notation $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, we must be able to prove that such a $y$ actually exists.

For example, consider the notation $f(x)$ (where both $f$ and $x$ are objects in set theory). In order that this notation be defined, we need that (1) $f$ is a function and (2) $x$ is in the domain of $f$. Formally speaking, we are introducing a partial binary function symbol $applyFunction(f, x)$ but writing it as $f(x)$ because it's shorter. In this case, the ternary predicate $P(f, x, y)$ is $P(f, x, y) = \ulcorner f$ is a function$\urcorner \land (x, y) \in f$ (where $\ulcorner f$ is a function$\urcorner$ is some formal way of saying $f$ is a function).

In set theory, perhaps the most general form of this notation is $\{y \mid Q(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y)\}$. We know that there is at most one set $Z$ satisfying the property of $\{y \mid Q(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y)\}$, but we don't know whether there is any such set $Z$ at all. Here, the predicate is $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n, Z) = \forall y (y \in Z \iff Q(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y))$.

In this case, we can indeed define $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i = \{x \mid \exists j \in I (x \in A_j)\}$. This is an example of a partial definitional extension.

We then need to prove a theorem.

> Theorem: Let $A$ be a function and let $I$ be its domain. Suppose that for all $i \in I$, $A_i$ is a set. Then $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i$ is well-defined.

Proof: we know that because $A$ is a function, $range(A)$ is well-defined. It turns out that $\bigcup range(A)$ is exactly the set which satisfies the defining property of $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i$.

I will note that there is one other strategy which is commonly used in set-theory texts. This is to make all notation a proper definitional extension, but to have the notation refer to a "garbage value" unless some preconditions are met. For example, we could define $f(x)$ to be $\{y \mid \exists z ((x, z) \in f \land y \in z)\}$. It turns out that this makes $f(x)$ well-defined even without assuming that $f$ is a function and that $x$ is in its domain. However, $f(x)$ would be a "nonsensical value" unless these conditions are met. It's even possible in classical logic to be more explicit and say "$f(x)$ means blah if these conditions are satisfied: otherwise, it means the empty set", making the "garbage value" behaviour specific.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it is exactly what I needed. Just to make sure, was anything I said in my question incorrect or was it just incomplete? I do have some questions regarding your answer, though. Would the following be an example of the definitional extension: Let $f:I \to S$ be a function, where $S$ is a set that only contains other sets. Then for all $i \in I$ there exists a unique $A \in S$ such that $f(i)=A$. Then we can define $A_i:=f(i)$ by definitional extension.  Did I understand this correctly or is that wrong?

Comment: Another example might be when we define functions the very first time. If $f:X \to Y$ is a function and $x \in X$, then there exists a unique $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y) \in f$. We can then denote this $y$ by $f(x)$ by definitional extension. So, if I get it correctly, this rule is exactly what allows me to introduce/define new notation, right?